# Excel 2010 - Merging two "IF" functions in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I apologize in advance if my explanation is confusing haha

I have two cells (D2 and D4) that I want to add up, but there are two conditions based on two other cells (B2 and B4): "if B2 is less than 1, the value in D4 isn't included".
 "If B4 is greater than 75, the value in D2 isn't included". In that case, if B2 is less than 1 and B4 is greater than 75, the result should be 0.

[image: pic1]

I've tried using IF functions to solve this (they're in cells F2 and F4 in the picture):

```
=IF(B2<1;D2;D2+D4)
=IF(B4>75;D4;D2+D4)
```

But I need to merge them in one cell. I thought it would work if I used `=IF(B2<1;D2;IF(B4>75;D4;D2+D4))`, but rather than resulting in 0 if B2<1 and B4<75, it ignored the second condition and gave me the "true" value of the first one (D2).

[image: pic2]

Is there any way I can make this work, maybe rearranging the IF formula in a different way, or maybe even with a different formula or procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with no IF statements at all:

```
= (B4<=75)*D2 + (B2>=1)*D4
```

This uses the fact that logical tests are treated as `1` if true and `0` if false.

So you want to include D2 only if B4 <= 75.  The expression in the first parentheses tests that.  If it's true, you get `1 x D2`.  If false, you get `0 x D2`.

The same kind of logic applies to D4.  Then you add whatever values are there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula:
**=IF(B2<1;IF(B4<=75;D2;0);IF(B4<=75;D2+D4;D4))**
in your formula you did not check when B2 <1 if B4 > 75

Answer (score 0):

I am having a bit of a hard time following what you are trying to do, but from what I can gather, you either want to use the AND function or the OR function inside of your if. Those are the two basic ways of combining two different conditionals.

AND: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9

OR: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-or-function